# Assigning Foreign Key with Django's CreateView

Tags: python, django

I've been wrestling with this all day. I'm attempting to come up with a solution to save multiple pictures per single form. I feel like I'm on the home stretch, but my issue now is I can't for the life of me get the ForeignKey to auto assign when the form is submitted. The code below is functional in every way other than no FK is applied to the DB record. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Attempting to pass:

```
FA_Attachments.objects.create(
                    image=f,field_evaluations = request.POST.get('order'))
```

Just gives me:

```
Cannot assign "'test'": "FA_Attachments.field_evaluation" must be a "FieldEvaluation" instance.
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class FieldEvaluation(models.Model):
    "Our default field evaluation form"
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class FA_Attachments(models.Model):
    field_evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        FieldEvaluation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import FieldEvaluation, FA_Attachments


class FieldEvaluationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FieldEvaluation
        fields = ['order']  # not attachments!

    attachments = forms.ImageField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import *
from .models import *


class FieldEvaluationView(CreateView):
    model = FieldEvaluation
    form_class = FieldEvaluationForm
    template_name = 'QA.html'
    success_url = '?success'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('attachments')
        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                FA_Attachments.objects.create(
                    image=f)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with overriding `form_valid` instead of `post` method. In `form_valid` you can save your field_evaluation object and than you can assign this new object to ForeignKey field. At the end you call and return `form_valid` with form as argument.

```
class FieldEvaluationView(CreateView):
        model = FieldEvaluation
        form_class = FieldEvaluationForm
        template_name = 'QA.html'
        success_url = '?success'

        def form_valid(self, form):
            field_evaluation_obj = form.save(commit=True)
            files = self.request.FILES.getlist('attachments')
            for f in files:
                FA_Attachments.objects.create(image=f, field_evaluation=field_evaluation_obj)
            return super(FieldEvaluationView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Right. It's logical, since you use this object an asign it to foreign key. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't save the ForeignKey!

First of all I suggest you to make the attachment relation mandatory:

```
class FA_Attachments(models.Model):
    field_evaluation = models.ForeignKey(
        FieldEvaluation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

I removed the `null=True` because this Model is strictly related to the FieldEvaluation

Then you must modify your POST.

```
class FieldEvaluationView(CreateView):
    model = FieldEvaluation
    form_class = FieldEvaluationForm
    template_name = 'QA.html'
    success_url = '?success'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('attachments')

        # your form must have it!
        order = request.POST.get('order')
        fe = FieldEvaluation.objects.create(order=order)

        if form.is_valid():
            for f in files:
                # here you create the relation with the FieldEvaluation
                FA_Attachments.objects.create(
                    image=f, field_evaluation=fe)
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Thank you! That null=true was in there for hunting down another bug earlier. Good spot. Unfortunately the solution you posted gives me: 'Cannot assign "'test'": "FA_Attachments.field_evaluation" must be a "FieldEvaluation" instance.' That's what's got me puzzled.

Comment: Is very confusing your model, but I fix my code, now it will work.